# Docker build-push-action "iidfile missing from /tmp/" when running with an arm self-hosted runner

Tags: git, docker, github, github-actions, buildx

I tried switching a workflow from ubuntu-latest to a self hosted arm runner, but got this weird error.

`Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: open /tmp/docker-build-push-m9gSaF/iidfile: no such file or directory`

When checking /tmp/ when the action is run, it looks like nothing is getting added to the /tmp/docker-build-push directory.

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: frontend
          file: frontend/Dockerfile
          platforms: linux/arm64
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/langaracpsc/langaracpsc-next:latest
```

Sample actions run: https://github.com/langaracpsc/langaracpsc-next/actions/runs/6101537965/job/16558257594

Comment: On the bright side, it looks like the error occurs after the package is pushed to github - but it still means that the workflow fails